# Bad status line exception while opening a page on django development server

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium

I am executing selenium test cases via Proboscis, for good reporting of test results. I have the following test case written

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from proboscis import test
import unittest
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

@test(groups=["unit","login"])
class UI_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_SuccessfulErrorMsgOnEmptyUserName(self):
        driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:7999/login/")
        username_input = driver.find_element_by_id("id_email")
        username_input.send_keys('')
        password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")
        password_input.send_keys('bill3')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value = "Log In"]').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("error-login")

driver.close()  

def run_tests():
    from proboscis import TestProgram
   # from tests import unit

    # Run Proboscis and exit.
    TestProgram().run_and_exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

What could be causing the `BadStatusLine` exception in this code?

Comment: please post full traceback

Comment: good question not sure

Comment: try doing the same on a browser. There must be a problem with http://127.0.0.1:7999/login answering correctly.

Comment: Why the port is 7999 in the example?

Comment: @alecxe Port is 7999, because server for my UI app is configured to run at that port. Thanks

Comment: Again, please post a traceback

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a duplicate of [Python/Django "BadStatusLine" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734617/python-django-badstatusline-error) but i can't flag due to this question having a bounty. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27530824/819417), a `BadStatusLine` exception is likely caused by an empty response, as in there being no status line at all.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483487/819417), the server formally tells the client there is no more data, instead of simply causing a connection reset or rude timeout.